# Django if with booelan property

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I create an if statement in Python/Django template that compares a booelan property?

Things I've tried so far:

```
{% ifequal gallery.draft True %}style="display:none"{% endifequal %} -> never
{% if gallery.draft %}style="display:none"{% endif %} -> always
```

Thanks in advance!

BTW, I'm doing this in the templates because I'm using AppEngine and I cannot sort and filter by different fields, and I need to sort by date.

Comment: What is the actual value of gallery.draft in that context? You can find out by doing `{{ gallery.draft }}`.

Comment: What part of AppEngine doesn't let you use Python functions like filter(), list.sort() or list comprehensions ?

Comment: `{% if gallery.draft %}` should work, try outputting the value as daniel said...

Comment: Why are you doing `{% ifequal gallery.draft True %}`?   Why not do `{% if gallery.draft %}`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending in "True" as a string to the template? That would not show up in a normal template printout. In that case just adding quotes to the first version would work.